# Unable to install MSSQL Drivers PHP on Ubuntu 20.04I

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I am basing myself on this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu18

Which gives the commands>

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 21.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

But I keep getting the following errors

```
root@ip-172-31-80-13:/home/ubuntu# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql18
root@ip-172-31-80-13:/home/ubuntu# # optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
root@ip-172-31-80-13:/home/ubuntu# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools18
```

I have tested on a new instance and I get the same error

Comment: Have you reviewed the files in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder yet? Seems like you could have another .list file that references a different version of Microsoft's product repository.

Comment: Its on a brand new instance. I only have ```deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic main``` in sources.list.d

Comment: Could the instance be hosted on a macOS/M1/ARM64 architecture? What's the output of `echo $HOSTTYPE`? Also your prodlist is referencing `18.04` whereas the question's subject says `20.04`, so there's already some discrepancy here.

Comment: It seems the problem was ARM, I changed to x86 and it installed. Now I am getting the following error ```SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate] (SQL: SHOW TABLES) (View: /var/www/html/uvk/resources/views/index.blade.php)```

Comment: SQL Server installs with a self-signed X.509 certificate, so it won't be trusted by any of the standard CA certs in Trusted Root Certificates on client machines. ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server and JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server both recently had a breaking change, changing to `Encrypt=1/True/Yes;` by default, so you need to do one of three things: 1) extract the public key of the target SQL Server and add it to your client's Trusted Root Certificates store, or 2) add `TrustServerCertificate=True;` to your connection string, or 3) add/change to `Encrypt=False;` in your connection string.